# Electron packaging apps issues- license and node.dll

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, macos, electron

I created an electron application in node.js that runs well on my mac. But I tried to package it using

```
electron-package . --all
```

as shown here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/

That runs successfully and makes apps for linux, mac, and windows.

Problems I'm running into:

1. The icon for the application is still the default electron one. I changed mainWindow to be this:

   `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
       width: 800,
       height: 600,
       icon: file://${__dirname}/assets/img/mylogo.png
     })`

EDIT: Resolved this issue by running
    `electron-packager . --platform=mas --arch=x64 --icon=assets/img/app.icns --overwrite`

(with tick marks around the icon path). What else am I missing to change the app icon?

2. On mac, when a user tries to open my app, they can't install because of this message:

   `"AppName" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.`

This is odd because there is a LICENSE file in the packaged .app folder that is made by Github. What's missing here?

3. On windows, when a user tries to open the app, they get this error:

   `node.dll is missing from this computer`

This seems off because the user shouldn't have to install extra things just to get my application to work. Did I screw something else up here too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should really try to avoid packing multiple questions into a single post.

1. (already answered yourself)
2. While electron-packager should in theory sign your apps (at least that's how I understand the respective readme entry), it seems your app has not been signed properly. Have you followed [the tutorial that can be found at the github page](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide.md)?
3. Please check:

   - Did you copy the whole directory before executing or just the executable? (Electron executables are not self-contained)
   - Can you make sure that the node.dll can be found somewhere within the applications folder or within its subdirectories?

Comment: Thanks, I'll recheck the 3rd one. For 2, I went to that link, but that's a guide for submitting the app to the mac app store. What if I just want to have it as a download like this guy does here (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Pi-Finder/releases - scroll to downloads)? If I just want downloads like that, do I still need to get an Apple Developer Account and ID?

Comment: I can't really be certain (I don't own a Mac), but this kind of code signing seems to be necessary for all distributed apps.

Comment: So I searched folder that was output by that electron-packager command -- App-win32-x64 -- and did indeed find a node.dll file there. Right below it is a App.exe. I'm unfamiliar to packaging windows apps -- is there another step I need to take? Which file do I give to people to install this? App.exe? That doesn't include node.dll. How do I put the two together?

Comment: You need to supply the complete folder including _all_ of its contents. Take a look at [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) if you would like to package it for distribution